# Saving timetable details in multiple rows a sql table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

in this system user will see a basic timetable view and he can add subjects by using a dropdown in each list.I need to store all the subjects in the timetable in a sql table. when a user selects a subject using a dropdown a new sql row should be created with start,end time,day and subject_code.Can someone please help

[image]

SQL table -> timetables(id,start,end,day,subject_code)

SQL table -> timetables(id,start,end,day,subject_code)

Time Table Controller

```
@Controller
public class TimeTableController {
    @Autowired
    private TimeTableDAO timeTableDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

    @Autowired
    private DayDAO dayDAO;

    @Autowired
    private TimeDAO timeDAO;


    @RequestMapping("/timeTable")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetails= timeTableDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableDetails",timeTableDetails);
        return "timeTable";
    }



    @RequestMapping("/timeTable/new")
        public String addTimeTable(Model model){
        TimeTable timeTable =new TimeTable();
        model.addAttribute("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectDetail);


        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetail = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("studentGroups",studentGroupDetail);

        return "addTimeTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTable/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTable") TimeTable timeTable){
        timeTableDAO.save(timeTable);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTable/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateTimeTable(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateTimeTable"));

        TimeTable timeTable = timeTableDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetails = subjectDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("subjects", subjectDetails);

        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetails = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("studentGroups",studentGroupDetails);

        List<Day> dayDetails = dayDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("days",dayDetails);

        List<Time> timeDetails = timeDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("times",timeDetails);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTable/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        timeTableDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }
}
```

TimeTable DAO

```
@Service
public class TimeTableDAO {

    @Autowired
    TimeTableRepository timeTableRepository;

    //to save a time table
    public TimeTable save(TimeTable timeTable){
        return timeTableRepository.save(timeTable);
    }

    //to save all the records of time table
    public TimeTable saveAll(TimeTable timeTable){
        return timeTableRepository.save(timeTable);
    }


    //to search all        
    public List<TimeTable> findAll(){
        return timeTableRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get by id
    public TimeTable findById(Long id){
        return timeTableRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


    //delete a machine
    public void delete(Long id){
        timeTableRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

updateTimeTable view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timeTable.css" th:href="@{/css/timeTable.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/timeTable/save}" th:object="${timeTable}" method="post">

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="year"><h1><input style="font-size:40px;" type="text"  th:field="*{year}" readonly="readonly"/></h1></div>
        <div class="Semester"><h1>Semester</h1></div>
        <div class="sem"><h1><input style="font-size:40px;" type="text" th:field="*{semester}" readonly="readonly"/></h1></div>
        <div class="TimeTable"><h1>Time Table for</h1></div>
        <div class="StudentGroup"> <h1>Student Group</h1></div>
        <div class="CS2"><h1><input style="font-size:40px;" type="text" th:field="*{group_code}" readonly="readonly"/></h1></div>


    </div>

</form>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
    <br><br>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/timeTable/save}" th:object="${timeTable}" method="post">
    <table border="1" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <th></th>
        <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                <th th:text="${day.name}"></th>
        </th:block>


        </thead>
        <tbody>


                <th:block th:each="time : ${times}">
                    <tr>

                        <th th:text="${ time.start }+':00 - ' + ${ time.end }+':00'"></th>

                        <th:block th:each="day : ${days}">
                            <td>
                                <select th:field="*{subject_code}">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option th:each="subject: ${subjects}" th:value="${subject.subject_code}" th:text="${subject.name}"/>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </th:block>




                    </tr>
                </th:block>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{group_code}" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{year}" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{semester}" readonly="readonly"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit">Save</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Help with what, precisely?

Comment: when someone click submit, all the selected subjects(in the timeTable view) should be stored in unique rows(in mysql table) which has a composite key(start,day,subject_code). I'm new to spring boot and have no idea how to do this. If you know how to do please help. Thank you